# How to write a MySQL if else endif statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I'd like a simple example of a MySQL if, else, endif statement.

I want to do something like this (in Java):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  `table` WHERE  `userID` =  1

if(count == 0){
  INSERT INTO  `table` (`userID`,`A` ,`B`)VALUES ('1',  '323',  '232')
}
else{
  UPDATE  `table` SET  `A` =  '323', `B` =  '232' WHERE  `userID` =1
}
```

Comment: by looking at your code I can suggest you use INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MySQL has `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` that allows you to update if the value already exist or Insert if not.

First you need to setup a `UNIQUE` Constraint,

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (ID)
```

that's it if you want `ID` to be unique. (*This is just an example*)

```
INSERT INTO tableName(userID, A, B) 
VALUES (1, 323, 232)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE  A = 323,
        B = 232
```

- [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: That exact statement isn't working, its not inserting if there is a duplicate. Is there something missing?

Comment: @EricBanderhide It's totally normal, it will just update the current record if the key already exist. What's else do you need to do?

Comment: It'll insert fine if the key doesn't exist. But not if it does, I've set the table to be unique. I've updated my question could you have a look at my statement?

Comment: what if the primary key already existed? what do you want to do with it?

Comment: I didn't add a primary key, I thought that was the effect of calling userID unique?

Comment: I think you need to index the unique key for INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to work. Unique is not enough.

Comment: @EricBanderhide Unique is the same with primary key as they are distinct values.

Comment: Cannot edit above for some reason. You update A = A and B = B so you see no effect. Maybe you mean A = 5.05 and B = 5.0

Answer (score 5):

The if statement (in a stored block):

```
IF search_condition THEN statement_list
    [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END IF
```

Or the if function (in-line):

```
IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)
```

which works as:
IF( condition, what_to_do_if_true, what_to_do_if_false )
The last part being the same as an 'else'.  An if-else-if would need to be embedded like:

```
SELECT IF( id==1, "1", IF( ID==2, "2", "Neither" );
```

Which would do the same as this in most programming languages:

```
if( id == 1 ) {
    print "1"
} elsif( id == 2 ) {
    print "2"
} else {
    print "Neither"
}
```